# "Did she turn" Vs. "she turned her face"

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

[Source](https://books.google.jo/books?id=dm8fqg9B8DEC&pg=PA9&dq=and%20only%20when%20he%20had%20come%20close%20to%20her%20did%20she%20turn%20her%20face%20toward%20him&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi66fuQsPPVAhVRrRQKHRa0CqAQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=and%20only%20when%20he%20had%20come%20close%20to%20her%20did%20she%20turn%20her%20face%20toward%20him&f=false) Anna Karenina

> - ... and only when he had come close to her ***did*** she turn her face toward him.

-initially, I thought that is a question, but I didn't find a question mark. So what "did" has to do with the text.

Furthermore, the writer, I think, could have written the sentence in this way: ...to her she turned... "without inserting (did)"

What is the explanation for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **inversion**.
If a **negative** adverb or adverbial expression is put at the beginning of a clause for emphasis, it is usually followed by **auxiliary verb + subject.** Inversion is also used after **restrictive words** like hardly (in
BrE), seldom, rarely, little and never
, and after only +
time expression
. This is formal or literary.

*Under no circumstances **can we cash** cheques.
At no time **was the President aware** of what was happening.
Not until much later **did she learn** who her real father was.* *Only then **did I understand** what she meant.
Only after her death **was I able** to appreciate her.*

M.Swan *PEU*